# How to minimize window?

Tags: hta, windows-shell, wsh, windows-scripting

How to minimize window?

I am making HTA application and I want replace window title bar with my custom one.
I've disabled it by HTA's "caption=no" option and placed my own minimize/maximize/close buttons.

I found two ways to minimize window:

- Shortcut ALT + SPACE + n
- Shortcut WinKey + ArrowDown

So I could send this shortcuts to window using WScript.Shell's SendKeys method.

```
WsShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.SendKeys("% n")
```

But the first one can't be used because there is no title bar, and the second because WinKey doesn't work with SendKeys.

I found MinimizeAll() method of Shell.Application, but it's alone.

Is there any other way to minimize the window? May be another activeX object or shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with exact the same issue. This is the solution that worked for me:

Place in the <**head**> section:

```
<object id="HHCtrlMinimizeWindowObject" classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11">
    <param name="command" value="minimize" />
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
function _jsMinWin( ) {
    try {
        HHCtrlMinimizeWindowObject.Click( );
    }
    catch ( err ) {
        alert( err.message );
    }
}
</script>
```

Then on <**body**> section something like:

```
<input type="button" value="Minimize Window" name="MinimizeWindow" id="MinimizeWindow" onclick="javascript:_jsMinWin();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use Tasks property of Microsoft Word Application object. First instantiate Microsoft Word Application object by passing the ProgID "Word.Application" to the `new ActiveXObject` command:

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

Then, find your HTA window among the Tasks collection:

```
var win = word.Tasks.Item(document.title);
```

As you can see, you should pass the title of your HTA to the Item method to find your HTA's window. But there is a problem... What if an another unwanted window has the same title as your HTA? This leads to a window confusion. To work around this problem, I recommend you to set a special and unique title for your HTA before you find your HTA window among the Tasks collection. This complicates things:

```
document.title = "window" + Math.random();
win = word.Tasks.Item(document.title);
document.title = "My HTA";
```

Please note that you should set your own desired title after you find your HTA window. Also note that this code should run when `window.onload` event occurs. Because that's when your HTA generates its window.

Then, whenever you need to minimize your HTA window, set the `WindowState` property of `win` object to `2`:

```
win.WindowState = 2;
```

Edit: On the other hand, this way has two disadvantages:
1. It runs properly provided that the user has Microsoft Office Word installed on his computer.
2. Instantiating Microsoft Word Application object takes a few seconds because this object runs in an out-of-process server. So this may slow down your HTA.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily silly way of approaching the problem. Among other issues, it'll fail if the user doesn't have Microsoft Word installed.

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, unluckily. But it was the only way that came to my mind. I'm sorry. Do you advise me to delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the [Microsoft scripting guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/08/18/how-can-i-minimize-or-hide-an-html-application-for-30-seconds/) doesn't know how to do it then it might not be possible.

Even if you could go all the way around with `ActiveXObject("shell.application").Windows.Item(x)` and get your own [InternetExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx) object, there doesn't seem to be a way to minimize yourself programmatically.

My only suggestion is to use something like `for (var k in obj) WScript.Echo(k)` on every window related object you can get your hands on and look for undocumented methods/properties...